# Force users to have last app version in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

I saw few posts about it but most of them seem to be outdated.

I have an app published in the Play Store and it has already published version codes 1 to 6.

I have found in those releases some serious bug and I published a new release with version code 7.

The new version has an in-app update to make sure in the next times that the users will update to the latest release but right now it won't make any effect on the previous releases since they didn't have this code in them. Is there a way I can make version codes 1 to 6 to download the latest version?

As long as users keep using versions 1 to 6 I can add some critical features and I need them to make this update.

Also, I use Firebase firestore/realtime database/fcm/storage/authentication. Is there a way I can do it from there? The only thing I can think of is to send cloud message for the users to update the app.

Thank you

Comment: "I use Firebase" Firebase has 18 or so products, so it'd really help if you say what parts of Firebase you use how in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can make version codes 1 to 6 to download the latest version?

No, sorry. Let your users know by whatever other communications channel(s) you established (site announcement, blog post, Twitter/Facebook/etc., email newsletter, ...).

Comment: Well, that's a good lesson for the future =]. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, for the users who are using version codes 1 to 6, there is not much you can do. I don't know what's the logic behind your existing "in-app update" option, but if the users can skip that step, you end up having the same problem.

To solve this kind of scenario, we usually add the version of the app to the database, and each time we open the app, we check that value against the one in the app's code. If there is a match, it means that no update is required, otherwise, we "force" the user to update the app to the latest version by opening the app's page from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/books).

Another solution might also be [Android In-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates):

> When your users keep your app up to date on their devices, they can try new features, as well as benefit from performance improvements and bug fixes. Although some users enable background updates when their device is connected to an unmetered connection, other users might need to be reminded to install updates. In-app updates is a Play Core library feature that prompts active users to update your app.