# I published an Android app on the play store. How do I push changes to users without requiring them to re-download

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

Several users have downloaded my app from Google Play. I now want to provide new features to them. How do I auto-update the app for them without requiring them to re-download the app?

Answer (score 0):

If they have the setting for downloading updates automatically set, just upload a new version of the app with a higher version number in the manifest.  The Play Store and Android will do the rest.  Of course if they turned off that setting they'll need to do it manually, but that was their decision when they changed the setting.

Answer (score 0):

> I now want to provide new features to them.

If you have added new features to your actual app in code, then the single option that you have, so that all users can see the updates is to re-download the app.

If you however want to force the users to get the latest version of your app, please check my answer from the following post:

> [Force users to have last app version in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478441/force-users-to-have-last-app-version-in-android/67482092#67482092)