# How to reset a whole project in Firebase, so previous users can not use auth and cloud functions

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I have been developing an app for the last 3 years. I started seeing strange emails pop up from time to time in my Auth page. There are only 4 persons that ever had any version of the app on their phone (it is Android). I asked all of them, those email accounts were not theirs.

All the emails are authenticated via Google Auth and all have this exact structure: "name.number@gmail.com"

Example: claireortiz.65705@gmail.com

There are like 10, idk if the app got out to some people, the github repo with the app is private.

I want to make the previous versions of the app unusable, how do I regenerate all of my authentication, functions and everything else or my google-services.json so any people that previously had any versions of the app can not access this firebase project. I do not want to create a new Firebase project, I just want people that do not have the newer version of the app to not be able to connect to this project. Maybe some API keys got out somehow, I want to reset it all.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478441/force-users-to-have-last-app-version-in-android) help?

Comment: No it does not. I just want the users that have the version of the app with the current google-json configuration to not be able to access my firebase project anymore.